# How to use data frame to scrap url links from the website using python and translate url links using google translation?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, google-translation-api

I am struggling to create a data frame, but the current works as it scrap the website title and course. Now i am struggling to write some functions using data frame that will count from the website as to how many url links it has. Thereafter must then translate these text context from the website(English into Hindi). Anyone who can help with me with this issue?

```
`# scrapping of the class-central.com website links
# this application uses selinium driver to access the web-pages
#

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = "https://www.classcentral.com/collection/top-free-online-courses"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

all_courses = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='catalog-grid__results')
course_titles = all_courses .find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[class="color-charcoal course-name"]')

for title in course_titles:
    print(title.text)
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but if you want to load all courses, you'll have to click on "Load more" until the button isn't available. You can get the URLs of the course via the `href`attribute:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.classcentral.com/collection/top-free-online-courses"
driver.get(url)

try:
    while True:
        # wait until button is clickable
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-name='LOAD_MORE']"))
            ).click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
except Exception as e:
    pass

all_courses = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='catalog-grid__results')
courses = all_courses.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[class="color-charcoal course-name"]')

df = pd.DataFrame([[course.text, course.get_attribute('href')] for course in courses],
                    columns=['Title (eng)', 'Link'])
```

Output:

```
                                           Title (eng)                                               Link
0                        Medical Parasitology | 医学寄生虫学  https://www.classcentral.com/course/edx-medica...
1    Understanding Medical Research: Your Facebook ...  https://www.classcentral.com/course/medical-re...
2    An Introduction to Interactive Programming in ...  https://www.classcentral.com/course/interactiv...
3                                        Mountains 101  https://www.classcentral.com/course/mountains-...
4                       Quantum Mechanics for Everyone  https://www.classcentral.com/course/edx-quantu...
..                                                 ...                                                ...
260                          Web Security Fundamentals  https://www.classcentral.com/course/edx-web-se...
261  Viral Marketing and How to Craft Contagious Co...  https://www.classcentral.com/course/wharton-co...
262                              Introduction to Linux  https://www.classcentral.com/course/edx-introd...
263            Bitcoin and Cryptocurrency Technologies  https://www.classcentral.com/course/bitcointec...
264  Machine Learning Foundations: A Case Study App...  https://www.classcentral.com/course/ml-foundat...

[265 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: thank you much, now my next step is find out how to use google trans to be able to translate all those courses as written in English into Hindi language, can you show me an example perhaps based on given output?

Comment: should be straight forward with [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/): `df['Title (hin)'] = df['Title (eng)'].apply(lambda x: translate(x, dest='hi'))`

Comment: what cause this error DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
I am using pycharm as IDE and all libraries are installed

Comment: The parameter has a new name: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`. It's only a warning though, it's safe to ignore

Comment: thanks for correcting me, do i use googletrans logic before data frame or after which line...?

Comment: This isn't part of your initial question. I wrote it above. Sth like `df['Title (hin)'] = df['Title (eng)'].apply(lambda x: translate(x, dest='hi').text)` after creating your df. I didn't test though. Please accept the answer if the question is solved

Comment: will accept now, how do print the data frame because i want to see how many as per your output.. please advice and translate has an error. I did import google_trans "unresolved reference"

Comment: Please take some time to do research on your own. These are basics. You have to install googletrans: `pip install googletrans` and you'll print with `print(df)`